# How to assert if jmeter response data is []

Tags: jmeter

On running jmeter script, I am getting Response code as []
How do I perform assert?

I tried Text response contains [] still jmeter could not pass and I got below message

Assertion failure message: Bad test configuration org.apache.oro.text.MalformedCachePatternException: Invalid expression: []
Unmatched [] in expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using Response Assertion in "Contains" or "Matches" mode.

According to [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide:

> The Pattern can be either be:
>
> a “string” for “Equals” or “Substring” clauses
>
> a “Perl5-style” Regular Expression for “Contains” or “Matches” clauses

So you need to:

- either switch to "Equals" or "Substring" Pattern matching rule and keep your pattern as `[]`
- or if you using "Contains" or "Matches" rule - you need to remember that square brackets are special [meta characters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) which represent character classes so they need to be escaped by forward slash like `\[\]`

Comment: The "Substring" option worked for me .Thanks